# ruby-progressbar expose count values

Tags: ruby, progress-bar

I want to access the count and total values from the ProgressBar instance. If they are exposed, I do not know how to get them. When I'm testing a loop, I may only want to iterate 10 times and break. It seems intuitive that either pb.increment would return the value, or that it would be an attr_reader value. Am I missing something?

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'

pb = ProgressBar.create(
    title:'Items',
    total:500,
    remainder_mark:'.',
    format:'%t |%B| %c of %C %p%%',
    length:80
)

i = 0
500.times {|x|
  pb.increment
  break if (i+=1) > 100
}
pb.stop
```

As you can see, I have to create and maintain a separate counter. It just seems so intuitive to say "break if pb.increment > 10", or at least do "pb.increment; break if pb.count > 10".

Thanks, dvn

Comment: can you try `pb.progress`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm an idiot. My IDE never presented it so I didn't think it was available. I'm still an idiot because I read the code and could not see how it was exposed (class Progress exists within another class).  Thanks again.

Comment: times passes the zero-indexed iteration numberto the block, so you could use x instead of i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You can access `progress` from the `pb` object, just as [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598834/ruby-progressbar-expose-count-values#comment86205455_49598834) suggested:

```
break if pb.progress > 100
```

---

According to the [docs](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar/wiki/Output-as-Hash), you can get all values as a hash with `to_h` and then use the `'progress'` value:

```
break if pb.to_h['progress'] > 100
```